# how to pass an implicit ordering to a class

Tags: scala

I've got this class

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)(implicit org: Ordering[Person])
```

It fails when trying to instantiate, because I'm not passing the ordering parameter properly.

```
object Person {
implicit def ageOrdering(a: Person, b: Person): Int = a.age compare b.age
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val people = Array(Person("aa", 30), Person("bb", 32), Person("cc", 19))
Sorting.quickSort(people)
}
}
```

How can I manage it?
Thanks

Comment: `ageOrdering` is of Type `Person, Person => Int` not of `Ordering[Person]` you probably want something along the lines of

`implicit val ageOrdering:Ordering[Person] = new Ordering[Person]{...}` however you might want to reconsider having an Ordering per Person e.g. if you want to sort a List of Person using that, which ordering from which person do you use?

its more usual to see the typeclasses used at the function site `def functionUsingPerson(p: Person, p1:Person)(implicit ord:Ordering[Person])`

Comment: You need to have implicit for `Ordering[Person]` try to replace your `implicit` definition with `implicit val order: Ordering[Person] = Ordering.by { p: Person => p.age }` and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `Ordering` as a member of `Person` does not seem to make any sense: why should every person have its own `Ordering`?

Furthermore, your implicit definition returns `Int`s, not an ordering.

Try this instead:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Person {
  implicit object AgeOrdering extends Ordering[Person] {
    def compare(a: Person, b: Person): Int = a.age compare b.age
  }
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val people = Array(Person("aa", 30), Person("bb", 32), Person("cc", 19))
    println(people.sorted.toList)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
List(Person(cc,19), Person(aa,30), Person(bb,32))
```